# How to stop removal of dots when file is downloaded?

Tags: php, html, url, download

I'm currently working on a test system where one part of the system is to download a work test, do the work test and then upload it. It works fine but I got one small problem and I'll try to explain it as clear as I can.

I have a download button that gets the file from a folder e.g. https://exampleURL.com/uploads/.NET.rar. Notice the dot before "NET.rar". When I browse the url it finds the file and starts the download correctly, BUT it gives me a file with the name "NET.rar" and not ".NET.rar" as it is called in uploads folder.

When I try to browse https://exampleURL.com/uploads/NET.rar without the dot is doesn't work because it can't find the file (obviously) because the file name is with a dot.

Does anyone have a good explanation to why the dot is removed and how I might fix it? It doesn't help to just "add" a dot aterwards because some files that are downloaded doesn't have dots before their name.

Thanks in beforehand.

Comment: Always post the code, we are not wizards.

Comment: The problem is not in the code, it's that for some reason when you type in the url to a file with a dot in the name it removes the dot. @machineaddict

Comment: The dot is removed by the Windows OS. There is nothing you can do about it. I just tested it. Just rename the file, maybe archive it with the dot (not tested).

Comment: I have a copy of it with a dot that I upload to the server folder so I am achiving it with the dot. When i check the folder in the server it has a dot. But when I download it it removes the dot. Very very weird. @machineaddict